# How to execute Mysql Queries in Ms Access 2007

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to run an mysql query in MS ACCESS 2007 using DoCmd.RunSql

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "update Table1 Join (select Table1.*, (@rn := if(@u = uname, @rn := @rn + 1, if(@u := uname, 1, 1) ) ) as rn from Table1 cross join (select @rn := 0, @u := '') params order by uname, id desc ) tt on t1.id = tt.id set Table1.flag = tt.rn;"
```

It showing Syntax Error.

Comment: When writing portable code, ANSI SQL is my number one tip. (The SQL Validator can quickly verify ANSI SQL syntax, http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml, a great time-saver when writing portable code.)

Comment: What does error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run *MySQL* syntax in *Access* this way.

The normal method to do that is to create a Pass-through query that connects to MySQL. It will pass the SQL directly to the server, thus this has to be of the dialect used by the server.

Or, of course, convert the MySQL syntax to Access SQL. Then `DoCmd.RunSQL` will work.